# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <, Angular 6 trying to connect to node server.js

Tags: json, node.js, express, google-maps-api-3, angular6

I am using `Angular6`, trying to serve json data from a google map API to make ajax calls to `Node.js` with `MongoDB`, I have a form for placing markers on a google map using the api, I am trying to set up node js to take in the json data so that it is not being stored on the local storage, I have being following tutorials trying to set up `Node.js`  to work with `express` and to store the places.

Using  `express`: "^4.16.3", `mongodb`: "^3.1.1",

I have created the dist folder with all of the relevant files and I have also created my server folder with route folder and api.js, also I have my server.js, I think that I have all in place but I keep getting this error in my console when I run it on the local host 3000,
[this is the error that is showing up in my google chrome console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lfe6f.png)

When I run http://localhost:3000/api it displays that the text 'api works'

This is my Server.js

```js
// Get dependencies
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const http = require('http');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

// Get our API routes
const api = require('./server/routes/api');

const app = express();

// Parsers for POST data
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

// Point static path to dist
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist')));

// Set our api routes
app.use('/api', api);

// Catch all other routes and return the index file
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'dist/mapit/index.html'));
});

/**
 * Get port from environment and store in Express.
 */
const port = process.env.PORT || '3000';
app.set('port', port);

/**
 * Create HTTP server.
 */
const server = http.createServer(app);

/**
 * Listen on provided port, on all network interfaces.
 */
server.listen(port, () => console.log(`API running on localhost:${port}`));
```

This is my api.js

```js
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

/* GET api listing. */
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('api works');
});

module.exports = router;
```

This is my index.html in my dist folder

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Mapit</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://bootswatch.com/4/simplex/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
<script type="text/javascript" src="runtime.js">
</script><script type="text/javascript" src="polyfills.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="styles.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="vendor.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have the following problem, you don't call next on your middleware and thus the HTML file cannot be send. You also try to call `res.send()` twice which you shouldn't do, `express` can only send one response. I suggest you change your api the following:

```
router.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
    console.log('api works');
    next();
});
```

Now the api works will logged in the terminal (nodejs) and not the browser console and the HTML should be send succesful.

Hopefully helps you!

Comment: I have added your code and I am still getting the same error :(

Answer (score 0):

Try app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist/mapit')));
Difference is using 'dist/mapit' instead of only 'dist'.

Answer (score 0):

Where have you placed your server.js file? I was seeing the same issue when I had my server.js within the DIST folder.

I moved the server.js file up one level so it is in the parent directory of the DIST folder and my site files css/js etc all loaded as expected.